# On ajax call recreate jsTree checkbox's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree, recreate

Hi I want to recreate jsTree with ajax call when radioButton "rdbFactTables" is clicked. 
I am using jQuery and jsTree scripts.

I get right output in cosole when i print "data" parameter, but from some reason tree won't recreate itself. Here are the snipets:

```
<p><input type="radio"  name="rdbFactTables" value="1">fSell</p>

<div class="green pull-left bottom">
   <div id="checkboxTree"></div>
</div>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
        $( "input[name='rdbFactTables']" ).click(function(){
            var idValue = $('input[name=rdbFactTables]:checked').val();
            var request = $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "/StarReporting/servlets/TreeProcessServlet",
                  data: { id: idValue}
                }).done(function( data ) {
                    //here i get data data printed in console but tree is not recreated
                      console.log(data); 
                      $('#checkboxTree').jstree('destroy');
                      $('#checkboxTree').jstree(data);
                  });
        });
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: I can recreate tree from Chrome console calling this:

Comment: $('#checkboxTree').jstree('destroy');

Comment: $('#checkboxTree').jstree({'core' : {'data':[{'id':1, 'text':'Root1'}, {'id':2, 'text':'Root2'}]},'plugins':[ 'wholerow', 'checkbox' ]});